# A query on gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I added 'dist' folder to .gitignore.
I expect that now this folder and its contents wont be tracked by git.

But when I do 'git status', I see:

> deleted:    dist/app.bundle.js
>
> deleted:    dist/favicon.png
>
> deleted:    dist/index.html

Why this behaviour?

Comment: it's because you had already committed these files. do a `git rm` on them, then `git add` your .gitignore, then you should be golden after a push.  those files will no longer be tracked after the commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+forget+tracked+files

Answer (score 0):

If you did a commit before you made the gitignore then the status is showing the files it's going to delete. Which are now in gitignore